# Why do my leiningen's repl show too many prompt message?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

```
D:\src>lein repl
nREPL server started on port 57504 on host 127.0.0.1
REPL-y 0.3.0
Clojure 1.5.1
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)
 Results: Stored in vars *1, *2, *3, an exception in *e

user=> (str "I don't want empty prompt!")
"I don't want empty prompt!"
user=>
user=> (println "Oh....")
Oh....
nil
user=>
user=> (exit)
Bye for now!
```

(screen shot is [here](http://ima.ge/J5OS0Q). I want to paste here, but I have no 10 reputation, sorry)

You can look a needless empty prompt message like `user=>`. Of course, it is not needed, and I didn't push enter key.

I have two questions:

1. Is this behavior regular? (I am sure it is not!)
2. and if it is not regular, do you have solution of this problem?

My Environment:

- Windows 8 64bit (Japanese)
- paste `lein -v`

  `Leiningen 2.3.4 on Java 1.7.0_21 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM`

Comment: That is not the case for Linux and OS X. Properly it is happening on Windows machines. My friend was also complaining about Lein on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess: Some systems (and I assume Windows here) use [CR+LF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Common_problems) for a single linebreak. For most of the UNIX world - and thus a lot of programmers/programs reading from standard input - these are *two*, making your output look as if you pressed Enter twice.

Maybe you can search for something like `<your terminal> disable crlf` to find a workaround.